# Install Broadcom wireless drivers on Ubuntu 18.10 "without internet"

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, 18.10

I have a desktop with an Asus Z170-Deluxe motherboard, which has onboard Wifi, and I'm trying to be able to use that to connect to the internet on Ubuntu 18.10.

First I thought it might be a good idea to try with the live USB, and when starting, there was no connection, but after doing A LOT of research, I found out I was able to go to `Software & Updates > Additional Drivers`, and there I could select this:

```
Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)
```

and then I could connect to the internet. So I thought the issue is resolved, and I installed Ubuntu 18.10, but after installation when I went to `Additional Drivers`, nothing was listed there :(

I'm not very familiar with Linux driver stuff, so again I started researching, and I found some that I wanted to try, but almost all of them included doing

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ...
```

but my problem is that I don't have a connection to the internet to be able to do any of those, and I don't have access to a wired connection.

PS: while I was trying things, I saw this item in the `Additional Drivers` tab:

```
Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (open source)
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: @karel Please note the duplicate says that it won't work in 18.04 (and, I can confirm, later) because `build-essential` is not installed by default.

Comment: The fact that it works in the live USB but not the final installation confirms that the needed packages are on the USB. Please see the duplicate but substitute USB for SD card.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments and linked questions. It seems that I did not need to go with all the packages listed in one of the linked questions, but a smaller subset. I'm going to provide an answer here in case anyone ends up in this question